# Illustrator C6 How to count the border width into the box dimension?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

Is there any way of telling Illustrator that I want it to include the border width into total dimension of the object?

For example I want a box 30x30px with 1px border. Of course I could make it manually and insert 29x29px for the box and then 1px stays for the border.
In this case it works, but what about when I change my mind during the creation process and want increase the border to 5 px? My box will be 34x34 px and I want it to always be 30, just different proportions between the fill and border. Does anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 2):

From the stroke panel set the stroke to align inside. The border width will then extend inwards from the width of your object.

[image]

Comment: Jesas, thank you so much - I ve been searching for it since this morning.

Answer (score 1):

Preferences > General > **Use Preview Bounds**

[image]

That option will take into account things which fall outside the paths of obects, such as the strokes or effects.

This will give you the *outer* meansurement, But it won't auto-adjust existing objects. In other words, if you have the option checked... and have a 40x40px rectangle with a 1pt stroke.... and increase the stroke to 5pts... it will make the rectangle 45x45px. But that *will* include the entire stroke in it's measurment.